# Eclipse console turned into black background after installing aptana plugin

Tags: eclipse, aptana, aptana3

I have installed in my eclipse (3.7.1) that i use for Java(JDT) development, aptana plugin because i'm working on some web project sometimes, now my console view have black background also when i'm in Java perspective ...

Why ?

How can i restore the default withe background of the console when i'm in Java perspective ? How can i do ?

[image: Eclipse Console View]

As you can see from the screenshot above the name of the console now is : "Aptana Scripting Console" , Why ?

The strange thing is that when i run the application in debug mode the console turn automatically with the default white background, and when i remove the debug instance the console turn black background again ...

Can i change the background color of a view for a specific perspective ?

**Update**

Switching to Eclipse theme from **Preferences > Aptana Studio > Themes**  i had my Console view white again, but remain the fact that the console is named "Aptana Scripting Console",
seems that aptana override the default eclipse console .

If i try to open the standard JDT Console, i can't because i don't have it in the list, the console appear only when i start debug my application :

[image: Available Console]

Maybe could be a bug of the plugin, or an incompatibility of eclipse with the plugin ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could change the theme from **Preferences** > **Aptana Studio** > **Themes**.  The default is **Aptana Studio**, which has the black background, and you could switch to **Eclipse**.

You could also disable **Enable Invasive Themes** from the same preferences page to just turn off Aptana theming on Eclipse views.

Comment: Ok, changing the theme, now the console background is white but remain the labe : "Aptana Scripting Console"

Comment: You could switch to other console of your choice from the dropdown array on the upper-right corner of Console view.

Answer (score 0):

On the right side there shall be a monitor-like icon with a down-arrow. Check if you have the standard console in that drop-down list.

Comment: Unfortunately i don't have it, and if i try with "New Console View", create another console view ever with black background.

Comment: Try to add -clean to shortcut when starting Eclipse, maybe some cached preference?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Aptana, but CDT had a similar issue a while back caused by a race condition when accessing the preference store. Maybe Aptana has fallen in the same trap?

- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=270326
- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=214215

The workaround for CDT was to manually reset the console background color, but since I don't have Aptana, I can't help you any further.